# numeric RewriteRule with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, numeric

I would like to send URL requests to a PHP script which will handle the 301.
The URI's I want to capture are dates, like 26-11-2010, without the dashes:

www.mysite.com/261110/ (6 digits)

What is the RewriteRule for this?
my script is

www.mysite.com/redirect.php?data=261110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6})/$ /redirect.php?data=$1 [L]
```

will match any string of 6 digits (whether they are dates or not)